# NavigateAsync doesn't navigate when viewmodel is injected

Tags: uwp, mvvm-light, template10, navigationservice

All day long, I'm calling

```
await this.NavigationService.NavigateAsync(typeof(Views.MyStankView));
```

And everything works great.
Until I x:Bind a button click to another viewmodel that inherits from (MVVM-Light's) ViewModelBase and (Template10's) INavigable that has a method

```
public async Task NavigateToMyStankView(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await this.NavigationService.NavigateAsync(typeof(Views.MyStankView));
}
```

The call to

```
await this.NavigationService.NavigateAsync(typeof(Views.MyStankView));
```

gets executed, but I don't GO anywhere.  From within this viewmodel and it's parent, neither OnNavigatingFrom get's called.  No errors, no navigation.

What gives?  Why is a bound/injected viewmodel's NavigateAsync not navigating?  While a "hard" viewmodel does navigate?

**EDIT:  Upon further inspection, this.NavigationService is null?!?  Why so?**

Comment: Not answerable this way. Create a [MCVE]

Comment: Does your `App` class in the `App.xaml.cs` inherit from `Bootstrapper`?

Comment: Maybe post some complete codes or share a basic sample so that others can investigates into it.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. The `NavigationService` property of your view-model is injected by the `NavigationService` during navigation. Something like `ViewModel.NavigationService = this;`. If you are injecting a view-model, then you are creating it, not the `NavigationService`, and so the property is null. But that's not the end of the world. You can easily work-around this by setting the `NavigationService` property of your view-model yourself, using the property value from the main view-model as your source. Something like this `var vm = new MyViewModel { NavigationService = this.NavigationService, Dispatcher = this.Dispatcher };`.

A good rule of thumb is this, if the `NavigationService` property is null, you won't be able to navigate with it. ;-) Just teasing. I hope this work-around makes sense.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jerry.

You mean like this?

    await this.NavigationService.NavigateAsync(typeof(Views.MyStankView), new MyStankViewModel { NavigationService = this.NavigationService });

that results in this (very apropos) error:

    Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll